# How to list URLs in directory and sub-directories?

Tags: powershell

I have a whole lot of files which have been archived to a cloud-based vault. The files themselves have been replaced in the Windows file tree by shortcuts. The shortcuts use the original file's name with the url file extension added to the end (eg: "document1.docx.url" or "document2.pdf.url").
I want to generate a list of all the shortcuts in the folders and subfolders, along with the URL which points to the file in the vault.

I can get a list of the .url shortcuts easily enough, but I'm having trouble listing the target URLs of the shortcuts.

What I've got so far is:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "G:\bss\AIS" |
         Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".url"}
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($item in $items) {
    $array.Add([pscustomobject]@{
        "Name File" = $item.name
        "Path" = $item.FullName
    }) | Out-Null
}
$array | Export-Csv G:\bss\AIS\test.csv
```

This gives me a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Name File   Path
Admin tips.doc.url  G:\folder1\folder2\Admin tips.doc.url
Cisco_Icon_Library.pdf.url  G:\folder1\folder2\Cisco_Icon_Library.pdf.url
AIS Ta ta for now.jpg.url   G:\folder1\folder2\AIS Ta ta for now.jpg.url
```

I want something which looks like this:

```
Name File   Path    URL
Admin tips.doc.url  G:\folder1\folder2\Admin tips.doc.url   http://www.thecloud.com/blahblahblah/Admin tips.doc
Cisco_Icon_Library.pdf.url  G:\folder1\folder2\Cisco_Icon_Library.pdf.url   http://www.thecloud.com/blahblahblah/Cisco_Icon_Library.pdf
AIS Ta ta for now.jpg.url   G:\folder1\folder2\AIS Ta ta for now.jpg.url    http://www.thecloud.com/blahblahblah/AIS Ta ta for now.jpg
```

Is there an easy way to list the URLs?

Answer (score 1):

changing your for loop to the below snippet should fix the issue:

```
foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $array.Add([pscustomobject]@{
        "Name File" = $item.name
        "Path" = $item.FullName
        "URL" = (get-content $item.fullname)[1].Replace("URL=","") }
        ) | Out-null
}
```